# Spark DataFrame TimestampType - how to get Year, Month, Day values from field?

Tags: python, timestamp, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Spark DataFrame with take(5) top rows as follows:

```
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=1, value=638.55),
 Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=2, value=638.55),
 Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=3, value=638.55),
 Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=4, value=638.55),
 Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=5, value=638.55)]
```

It's schema is defined as:

```
elevDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- hour: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value: double (nullable = true)
```

How do I get the Year, Month, Day values from the 'date' field?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Since Spark 1.5 you can use a number of date processing functions:

- [`pyspark.sql.functions.year`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.year.html)
- [`pyspark.sql.functions.month`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.month.html)
- [`pyspark.sql.functions.dayofmonth`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofmonth.html)
- [`pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek.html)
- [`pyspark.sql.functions.dayofyear`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofyear.html)
- [`pyspark.sql.functions.weekofyear`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.weekofyear.html)

```py
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, dayofmonth

elevDF = sc.parallelize([
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 2, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 3, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 4, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 5, 638.55)
]).toDF(["date", "hour", "value"])

elevDF.select(
    year("date").alias('year'), 
    month("date").alias('month'), 
    dayofmonth("date").alias('day')
).show()
# +----+-----+---+
# |year|month|day|
# +----+-----+---+
# |1984|    1|  1|
# |1984|    1|  1|
# |1984|    1|  1|
# |1984|    1|  1|
# |1984|    1|  1|
# +----+-----+---+
```

---

You can use simple `map` as with any other RDD:

```py
elevDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=1, value=638.55),
    Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=2, value=638.55),
    Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=3, value=638.55),
    Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=4, value=638.55),
    Row(date=datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), hour=5, value=638.55)]))

(elevDF
    .map(lambda (date, hour, value): (date.year, date.month, date.day))
    .collect())
```

and the result is:

```py
[(1984, 1, 1), (1984, 1, 1), (1984, 1, 1), (1984, 1, 1), (1984, 1, 1)]
```

By the way, `datetime.datetime` stores the hour anyway so keeping it separately seems to be a waste of memory.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, it wasn't working for me before, but have it working now with `elevDF.map(lambda (date, value): (date.year, value)) `

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. For future readers, [reference for extraction time as well](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-extract-hour-minute-and-second-from-timestamp/)

Answer (score 34):

You can use functions in `pyspark.sql.functions`: functions like `year`, `month`, `etc`

Refer to PySpark's official [DataFrame documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) for details about available functions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

newdf = elevDF.select(year(elevDF.date).alias('dt_year'), month(elevDF.date).alias('dt_month'), dayofmonth(elevDF.date).alias('dt_day'), dayofyear(elevDF.date).alias('dt_dayofy'), hour(elevDF.date).alias('dt_hour'), minute(elevDF.date).alias('dt_min'), weekofyear(elevDF.date).alias('dt_week_no'), unix_timestamp(elevDF.date).alias('dt_int'))

newdf.show()


+-------+--------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------+
|dt_year|dt_month|dt_day|dt_dayofy|dt_hour|dt_min|dt_week_no|    dt_int|
+-------+--------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------+
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|     0|        36|1441497601|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|     0|        36|1441497601|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|     0|        36|1441497603|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|     1|        36|1441497694|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|    20|        36|1441498808|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|    20|        36|1441498811|
|   2015|       9|     6|      249|      0|    20|        36|1441498815|
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, we really do not need to import any python library. We can separate the year, month, date using simple SQL. See the below example,

```
+----------+
|       _c0|
+----------+
|1872-11-30|
|1873-03-08|
|1874-03-07|
|1875-03-06|
|1876-03-04|
|1876-03-25|
|1877-03-03|
|1877-03-05|
|1878-03-02|
|1878-03-23|
|1879-01-18|
```

I have a date column in my data frame which contains the date, month and year and assume I want to extract only the year from the column.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("res")
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT EXTRACT(year from `_c0`) FROM res ")
```

Here I'm creating a temporary view and store the year values using this single line and the output will be,

```
+-----------------------+
|year(CAST(_c0 AS DATE))|
+-----------------------+
|                   1872|
|                   1873|
|                   1874|
|                   1875|
|                   1876|
|                   1876|
|                   1877|
|                   1877|
|                   1878|
|                   1878|
|                   1879|
|                   1879|
|                   1879|
```

Comment: Note that this only works in Spark >= 3.0