# Add month column from timestamp column, Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `time` column, with timestamps of the form `2018-04-12 06:48:39` . How can I add a column `Month` from this timestamp, in this case containing 4 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrame TimestampType - how to get Year, Month, Day values from field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949202/spark-dataframe-timestamptype-how-to-get-year-month-day-values-from-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pyspark.sql.functions.month`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.month):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('month', F.month('time')).show()
+-------------------+-----+
|               time|month|
+-------------------+-----+
|2018-04-12 06:48:39|    4|
+-------------------+-----+
```