# Is there any functions in PySpark to give the "minute of day"?

Tags: function, pyspark, timestamp, hour, minute

I have a column with Timestamp.
I am wondering if there is a function that can give me the "minute of day" for each Timestamp.
I am looking for a function to give me an integer as an answer which shows how many minutes have passed from 00:00 which is beginning of day.
For example, Timestamp of 00:15 should become 15 or Timestamp of 01:05 should become 65 or Timestamp of 03:15 should become 195. (Basically it should do HH*60 + MM)

In the link below I could find a function which shows "day of year" But I could not find any functions for "minute of day"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30956282/12305290

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the PySpark SQL functions [hour](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour) and [minute](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.minute) the same way you suggested it:

```
In [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08 13:08:15',)], ['ts'])
df.
In [2]: from pyspark.sql.functions import hour, minute

In [3]: df.withColumn("minutes_since_midnight", hour(df.ts)*60 + minute(df.ts)).show()
+-------------------+----------------------+
|                 ts|minutes_since_midnight|
+-------------------+----------------------+
|2015-04-08 13:08:15|                   788|
+-------------------+----------------------+
```