# Extract year and month as string in Pyspark from date column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With Pandas, I can extract year and month by simply using;
`tb['yearmon'] = tb['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m'))`

How can I do this in Pyspark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark DataFrame TimestampType - how to get Year, Month, Day values from field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949202/spark-dataframe-timestamptype-how-to-get-year-month-day-values-from-field)

Comment: No it does not. I believe this solution does not retain the original columns and just get the new ones. I want to add another columns with yearmon.

Comment: Also, I want year and month in just one column. not separate.

Answer (score 4):

This  should work as you want it. Basically use the sql functions build into pyspark to extract the year and month and concatenate them with "-"

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['date'])
df.select(date_format("date", "yyyy-MM")).collect()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get months in two digit? like 01?

Comment: updated the answer